# why doesn't date show am or pm

Tags: sql, t-sql

Why am I not getting time with am or pm

```
DECLARE @inputDate varchar(25)
SELECT @inputDate = '3/13/2012 13:00'

-- Declare the return variable here 
DECLARE @Result DATETIME
DECLARE @toReturn NVARCHAR(25)

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here 
SET @inputDate = REPLACE(@inputDate, '24:00', '00:00')
SET @Result = null
SET @toReturn = null
IF (ISDATE(@inputDate)=1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @utcOffset int 
    SET @utcOffset = -(DATEDIFF(HH, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()))
    SET @Result = DATEADD(HH, @utcOffset, @inputDate)
    SET @toReturn = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @Result, 101)
END

-- Return the result of the function 
SELECT @toReturn
```

Returns only date portion?

Comment: Just so you know, not all timezones are offset from UTC by hours - you may want to use minutes, or something smaller.  Also, do you _really_ want to keep this as a string?  Date/time/timestamps are best left in those types.  You may also want to consider returning early if `@utcOffset` is `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change `CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @Result, 101)` to something else. `101` returns a mm/dd/yyyy format. See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are using `101` in your last convert statement and that is date only.

Have a look here for other options. [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try another date format instead of 101 in CONVERT operator.

Answer (score 0):

Because your final conversion uses a format that only includes dates - no time component.

Try the following, instead:

```
SET @toReturn = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @Result, 121)
```